# nodemon in Nodejs, is there a way to track the changes?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

When we install the nodemon package in NodeJS, is will restart hanging processors like webservers, and when you run an application after changing something in a file in nodeJs, the terminal will display that it is restarting due to changes...

As shown below

```
server running on port 3000 ...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app2.js`
server running on port 3000 ...
```

but is there a way to display what are the changes made in the terminal while it restarts?

Comment: Changes as in code changes... Changes in assets of the working directory will trigger the restart.

Comment: `nodemon -V . . .` for verbose